# Import syntax with TypeScript project references

Tags: typescript, tsc, tsconfig

What is the proper way to import modules from another sub-project in TypeScript?

I have this project structure:

```
myproject/
  tsconfig.json
  tsconfig-base.json
  src/
    tsconfig.json
    core/
      A.ts
      B.ts
    extra/
      C.ts
      D.ts
  test/
    tsconfig.json
    test.ts
  built/
    core/...
    extra/...
    test/...
```

tsconfig-base.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "built",
    "composite": true,
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "files": [],
    "includes": [],
    "references": [
        { "path" : "./src" }, 
        { "path" : "./test" }
    ]
}
```

src/tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "include": ["**/*"],
    "extends": "../tsconfig-base.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "rootDir": "."
    }
}
```

test/tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "extends" : "../tsconfig-base.json",
    "include" : ["*"],
    "references": [
        { "path": "../src" }
    ],
    "compilerOptions" : {
        "outDir": "../built/test",
        "rootDir": "."
    }
}
```

In `test/test.ts`, I do:

```
import { Thing } from "../core/A"
```

Because [this thread](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27572) suggests that modules should be imported "from wherever they end up" when using `outDir`, I would expect the above to work (because `built/core/A.js` is relative to `built/test/test.js` via the specified path). Similarly, the [TypeScript docs on project references](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html) show an example with similar structure with an `import` omitting "src" as above.

Instead, I get:

```
test/test.ts:1:28 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../core/A'.

1 import { Thing } from "../core/A"
```

Why is this? How does TypeScript search for imports when using project references? (Note that in this case, it would be untidy to be forced to include "`src/`" in all the import paths).

What is the proper way to accommodate the project structure above?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

By updating file src/tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "include": [
        "**/*"
    ],
    "extends": "../tsconfig-base.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../built/src",
        "rootDir": "."
    }
}
```

And run:

```
$./src  tsc
$./test tsc
```

I'll have a build structure like:

```
- built/
  - src/
    - core/ 
      - A.d.ts
      - A.js
  - test/
    - test.d.ts
    - test.js
```

And run:

$./myproject node built/test/test.js

It will work as expected. Doesn't it?

Comment: Nope, it does not.

Comment: I meant It does work for me. Transpiled and will be executed. Did you try it?

Comment: It didn't work in a freshly-created project with the exact structure as above, and didn't work in the original, larger project that prompted this question— I still get the `Cannot find module` error. Your example would seem to go against the two docs I linked (how would the generated JS know about "src/"?). If you did try it, I'm not sure what we are doing differently. What TS are you using? (Mine is 3.8.3).